# Rails template error implicit conversion string to string Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a function that looks at a stored string, converts to date, and outputs as formatted string:

```
  def due_date()
    d =  Configurable[:payment_due_date]
    Date.parse(d).to_formatted_s(:long)
  end
```

And a line in a template that spits it out bolded:

```
  %td{:colspan=>'8'}
    blah blah blah
    %strong= due_date(:data)
    blah blah blah
```

This works fine in dev and has been working fine in production on Heroku for years.  But all of a sudden I'm getting this lovely error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Sat, 09 Jun 2018 into String):
```

Where it sure seems like it still has the right thing to work with.  I thought maybe this was a increased level of html protection, or losing track of the fact that it was a string.  I tried this, but nothing changed.

```
%strong= "#{due_date(:data)}".html_safe
```

So obviously I'm going to be looking for any gem version changes triggered in recent deploys. But I'm just wondering if anyone out there has a notion of what failure might be leading to that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an effect of the Configurable Engine gem updating from 0.4.8 to 0.5.  I haven't yet been able to work out exactly why that should be--but locking back on 0.4.8 resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you try explicitly using:

`due_date(:data).to_s`

The error is the result of ruby not know which type to cast the date.

To better understand, try running the following in an IRB console:

```
> "3" + 4
=> TypeError (no implicit conversion of Integer into String)
```

In order to prevent unexpected behavior, it wants you to explicitly specify a type. If you don't, it's not totally clear whether you're looking for any of the following outputs:

```
7 #Integer
"34" #String
"7" #String
```

Hope this helps.

seb

Comment: I believe for Date to_s is just an alias of to_formatted_s.  Certainly if follow the steps in the console and do a to_formatted_s the result of that has class String.

Comment: I went ahead and tried an explicit to_s in the template, for lack of anything better to try, and on the off chance that some kind of scan of the template was deciding to throw an error without checking result of that method.  No change, same error.

Comment: hmmm... can you share an example of what is expected from `Configurable[:payment_due_date]` ?

Comment: '2018-06-09'  Again note that it works fine in development right now and has been working fine for years.  Also you can tell from the error message that the parse to Date and the output to formatted string are working correctly.  But how it is now looking at that output and not seeing a string is...puzzling.

Comment: That is confusing... I'm guessing you wrote psuedo code, however what's unclear to me is the symbol `:data` that's being passed to the `due_date` method, whose definition doesn't take an argument. What I would try too is using the same method but in a normal .erb template rather than .haml to see if it's a templating error.

Comment: It's not pseudo code, although I did prune out some complexity.  Configurable is a gem that basically gives a lookup table, so :payment_due_date is the key being used in a lookup operation.  That all is working fine.   :data as a parameter to due_date is what yields the :payment_due_date option, there are other possible args to due_date, that is the complexity I pruned out.  Isolating out haml is a good idea, thanks.

Comment: got it. Good luck and hope you're able to nail it as a haml issue